# JavaScript Number inheritance

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototypal-inheritance

So lets say I want to make a simple Price class in JS. It's basically a number so I thought I would just inherit from a Number. Here is some code:

```
Number.prototype.toMoney = function (precision, decimals, thousands) {
    // Formats number...
}

function Price(val) {
    Number.call(val); // Based on MozillaDN
}

Price.sufix = ' EUR'; // To print with every Price

// Price.prototype = Number.prototype;
Price.prototype = new Number(); // any difference?

Price.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.toMoney() + Price.sufix; // Of course it does not work.
}

var price = new Price(100.50);
alert(price.toString()); // Gives: undefined EUR
alert(price); // This fail. I thought it should work as it works with Numbers.
```

I probably do something wrong, but I can't find out what.

Comment: fyi, it's `suffix`, not `sufix`. `Number.call()` looks also a bit odd - I don't think you can invoke constructor functions like that.

Comment: This isn't going to work nicely I think, because "Number.prototype.valueOf is not generic". Although you have access to a `Price` instance, you can't get the underlying number value.

Comment: @pimvdb I was struggling with this already, but I thought it is possible tough. Does this mean I should just ignore inheritance and make a property inside Price class called "value" for ex.?

Comment: @ThiefMaster https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript Just saw it here. It also seems odd to me.

Comment: The idea would be correct, but with the "not generic" errors I'm afraid you're out of luck inheriting native functions, I think. You're calling `Number` on a `Price` instance. You still don't have a true `Number` value that you can call `valueOf` on.

Comment: By the way, I think you meant `Number.call(this, val)` to inherit `Price` from `Number` - but it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Using `Number.call(this, val)` and `Price.prototype = Number.prototype` works fine more me. Make sure that `Number.prototype.toMoney` returns a proper value. On the other side, I don't see a reason why to extend the a native object.

Comment: I stand corrected - I left the function blank... I'd recommend `Price.prototype = new Number` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this line I think:

```
Price.prototype - new Number(); // any difference?
```

You are assigning a new Number to be the prototype of Price so you need to use an = sign not a minus sign.

It should read:

```
Price.prototype = new Number(); // any difference?
```

Having said that, it still doesn't work. I can't understand why you are attempting to inherit from Number.

This works:

```
function Price(val) {
    this.val = val;                
}
Price.suffix = ' EUR'; // To print with every Price

Price.prototype = {
    toString: function() {
        return this.toMoney() + Price.suffix;
    },
    toMoney: function(precision, decimals, thousands){
        //fancy code here to format the number
        return "formatted number " + this.val;
    }
};

var price = new Price(100.50);
alert(price.toString()); // returns: formatted number 100.50 EUR
alert(price);
```

Comment: This is just example typo, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

When I was looking for an answer for almost the same question, I found this page. As this helped me to make final conclusion, I liked to share it with you. It is really possible to inherit own objects from Number.

```
function Price(val) {
    Number.call(this, val);
}
```

This is how you normally call parent object's constructor, but in this case it doesn't work, since the constructor returns the `val` itself. And when you try to read the `val`, "Number.prototype.valueOf is not generic" error is received.

```
alert(price.toString()); // Gives: undefined EUR
alert(price); // This fail. I thought it should work as it works with Numbers.
alert(price.valueOf()); // This fails too! ()
```

Instead you should make a property inside Price class called `val`.

```
function Price(val) {
    this.val = val;
}

Price.sufix = ' EUR'; // To print with every Price

// Price.prototype = Number.prototype;
Price.prototype = new Number(); // any difference?
```

There is a way in JavaScript to do an inheritance object, the `Object.create()` method. And because the constructor object is now pointing to the parent's constructor, ...

```
Price.prototype = Object.create(Number.prototype);
Price.prototype.constructor = Price;
```

Finally, you can overwrite the `valueOf()` method to read the value:

```
Price.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return this.val;
    }

var price = new Price(100.50);
alert(price); //should work now
```

However, there is one side effect: if you need methods from Number object, you must call them like this:

```
alert(price.valueOf().toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is not doing what you think:

```
function Price(val) {
    Number.call(val); // Based on MozillaDN
}
```

When called as a constructor, the above will return a plain object (the function's `this` object), not the value returned by `Number.call(val)` which is the primitive value +0, regardless of the value of `val`. So even if you try to return it, the constructor will still return its *this* since constructors **always** return an object, even if you try to return something else.

If [Number is called as a function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.1), it does type conversion. Since no value is passed to it (the value of `val` is passed as its *this* object with no value supplied), the expression returns +0.

And what is the point of that anyway? Are you trying to create a Number object with a value of `val`? You are probably better off to give *Price.prototype* custom *toString* and *valueOf* methods that return appropriate values. Mimicking the same named methods of *Number.prototype* would make sense.

```
> // Price.prototype = Number.prototype; 
> Price.prototype = new Number();
> // any difference?
```

Yes, the second adds an extra Number object on the `[[Prototype]]` chain for Price instances. It means you can add properties and methods to Price.prototype without affecting Number.prototype.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
function Price(value, symbol) {
  this.value = value;
  this.symbol = symbol;
}

Price.prototype = {
  toString: function() {
    return '' + this.symbol + this.valueOf();
  },

  valueOf: function() {
    return this.value.toFixed(2);
  }
}

var x = new Price(10.50, '$');

alert(x + '\n' + (1*x)); // $10.50  10.5
```